# Django: how to optimize querying the database?

Tags: django, django-models

My models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    code = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        related_data = self.relateddata_set.all()
        tickers = ", ".join(related_data.values_list("ticker", flat=True))
        titles = set(related_data.values_list("title", flat=True))
        return f"{tickers} - {titles.pop()} - Code {self.code}"


class RelatedData(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False, blank=False, db_index=True)
    title = models.TextField(default="")
    search_vector_title = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(
                OpClass(Upper("ticker"), name="gin_trgm_ops"),
                name="ticker_gin_idx",
            ),
            GinIndex(fields=["search_vector_title"]),
        ]
```

I often perform the following search:

```
search_input = "Some_input"
for item in Company.objects.filter(
    Q(relateddata__ticker__icontains=search_input)
    | Q(relateddata__search_vector_title=search_input)
).distinct():
    print(item)
```

I can't have everything in `Company` model because companies may have several instances of `RelatedData`.

Questions:

1. How to optimize the `__str__` method of `Company` model?
2. Is it possible to improve the efficiency of search? How?

Answer (score 0):

The `__str__` method of `Company` model is hard and is called often. So I decided to prepare it in advance, store it as a field in the model, and also update it using Django signals whenever the related instance of `RelatedData` model is updated.

Updated Company model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    code = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    str_stored = models.TextField(default="")

    def update_str_repr(self) -> str:
        tickers_title_data = self.codetickertitle_set.all().values_list(
            "ticker", "title"
        )
        tickers = set()
        titles = set()
        for item in tickers_title_data:
            tickers.add(item[0])
            titles.add(item[1])
        tickers_str = ", ".join(tickers)
        company_title = titles.pop().title() if titles else "Title N/A"
        self.str_stored = (
            f"{tickers_str} - {company_title} - SEC Code {self.code}"
        )
        self.save()
        return self.str_stored

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.str_stored:
            return self.update_str_repr()
        return self.str_stored
```

Signal (`signals.py`):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from company.models import CodeTickerTitle


@receiver(post_save, sender=CodeTickerTitle)
def my_callback(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.company.update_str_repr()
```

Signal import into the app configuration (`apps.py`):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class CompanyConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "company"

    def ready(self):
        import company.signals
```

Initial `str_stored` field filling:

```
companies_total = len(Company.objects.all())
counter = 0
for item in Company.objects.all():
    counter = counter + 1
    print(f"Processing company {counter} of {companies_total}...")
    item.update_str_repr()
    print(item)
    print()
```